# Error given in react-native when npm start

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am using 
Node - v10.6.0
Npm version -4.6.1

When i tried to execute the commad npm start under my project folder, it is giving an error

my_app@0.1.0 start /mnt/E/react_native/my_app

> react-native-scripts start

`sh: 1: react-native-scripts: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! my_app@0.1.0 start:`react-native-scripts start
`npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Please help to rectify the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running your code on MAC. If yes then please try running below command:

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname directory
```

where "username" is your current user name, "groupname" is your primary group and "directory" is your project directory path.
Afterwards remove node_modules folder and try below commands:

```
npm install
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, Surprisingly it works fine in Windows but failed in Linux giving the same error. Follow below step to resolve this issue.

you need to change `package.json` file inside your project folder like below instead of default value of `"start": "react-scripts start"`

> "scripts": {
>       "start": "`node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`" }

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024  
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

before

```
npm start
```

This will temporarily increase the number of files that the development server is able to monitor for changes. This solution is specific for Ubuntu/Linux - the macOS equivalent is "kern.maxfiles" and "kern.maxfilesperproc"

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed `webpack-dev-server` please do it by issuing the below command

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-dev-server
```

In case if you have already done it, try deleting your `node_modules` directory and run a fresh `npm install` before you execute your `react-native-scripts start` command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have necessary permissions, so you see:

```
sh: 1: react-native-scripts: Permission denied
```

Try starting it with :

```
sudo react-native-scripts start
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. It was running after executing sudo chmod -R 755 .

Answer (score 0):

I solved such a problem by making sure that my react-script binary was executable.

```
$ chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```